# Modal windows plugin to rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog

I'm starting to digg some rails plugins to create modal forms in rails. Almost all documents that you find are too old (2006,2007) or more focused in php. I would like to create a "feedback" tab that when you click on that, it opens a form. For example, you can check the railscast website, http://railscasts.com/. Ryan Bates made it in his website, but didnt make any screencast about it.

any idea/tip about a rails plugin to work with jquery and to do those forms?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check this tutorial on rails+jquery

[6 Steps to Unobtrusive Rails (with jQuery)](http://polyrails.com/2008/11/11/steps-to-unobtrusive-rails-with-jquery/) (Nov 2008 ok for you?)

Then just pick a jquery plugin that suits you and supports some kind of modal display. A little selection for you

- [Simplemodal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/)
- [Thickbox](http://codylindley.com/thickbox/)
- [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/)
- [nyroModal](http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/)
- Simple JQuery Modal Window
- Modal Panels
- Lightbox
- Block UI
- [JqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/)
- Pirobox
- [JQuery UI Dialog](http://www.etmvc.cn/project/show/61)
- [Facebox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox)
- Impromptu
- jDialog
- FancyZoom
- Choose Component
- jBox
- Greybox Redux
- Modal Dialog
- Smart Modal

Can't be bothered to insert links to all of them

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the above listing.  I find this link useful as well.  There are a few 
that aren't in the list above, and it gives some screen shots in the post. 
http://komunitasweb.com/2009/03/jquery-modal-box-round-up/