# How do jQuery modal box plugins compare?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, modal-dialog

There is a huge number of jQuery modal box plugins out there.  Jitter lists 20 of them in this response ([Modal windows plugin to rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656086/modal-windows-plugin-to-rails#1656105)).

Which one do you use and why?  If you use different ones in different cases, how can they be broken down categorically by use-case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I pick what I want based on its *primary* use. The fact that you can use a lightbox variant to show a dialog box, doesn't make it a good candidate in my mind.

Generally if I need to show photos or another iframed web page, I use a lightbox variant. Two that we have used at our studio and been happy with are:

1. [Slimbox 2](http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox2) (Just photos)
2. [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) (Pretty much any type of content)

For dialog type behavior, I highly recommend using [jQuery UI's dialog](http://ui.jquery.com). It is in active development, and is super customizable.

[rant] Whatever you do please don't use SimpleModal unless you need its special type of callbacks. Otherwise, when you try to hook into an `onClose` callback, you'll find yourself having to perform the actual closing of the box. Just my two cents on that one. :) I just know it has come up a few times here in SO, and it just feels awkward to use IMO [/rant]

Comment: Great analysis.  Thanks!  What about forms?  Does that fall under iframed website or a dialog box in your mind?  For example a form that closes the model box and modifies the original page when it is submitted?

Comment: No need to use an iframe for a form. Use jQuery UI Dialog. Its callbacks give you time to validate the form before really closing the box, etc. Check out their demo here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

Comment: LOL, just released I didn't actually answer your question. Since it is  form I would consider that a good candidate for a Dialog.

Comment: You answered it perfectly!  Thanks.  I'm moving forward to jQuery UI Dialog for my present need.

Comment: Thanks about the ColorBox. It is really awesome plugin for jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

I use Colorbox, it is because it is recommended alternative in [non-maintained thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/).

Basically it allows iframe, so image, flash etc are all okay. Also it is incentive for me to upgrade jQuery to 1.3.2 :-)

Comment: I guess I can check the documentation for this, but perhaps you know the quick answer from experience: do I have to use an iFrame?  What about just generating the content straight from javascript?  Forms?

Comment: You can use any type of HTML content with Colorbox, no iframe needed.

Comment: yes, you don't need iframe to display the box content, it is just a feature. btw, i use YAGNI approach. First capture what i need, then surf and find a lightbox that i don't need/change minimum of code to fit my need.

Comment: Thanks for recommendation. I think ColorBox will be mine new favorite jQuery Plugin. It looks really nice and small. +1 is coming here for this answer.

Comment: One more thing to mention is that since i pick jQuery. I won't pick a lightbox that need another js framework such as mootools/sciptaculous/prototype etc. So, the first thing i must do is deciding which JS framework i should use carefully when i start a project. Colorbox is small (9KB) and it is MIT(personally MIT is my favorite)

Answer (score 0):

JQuery UI Dialog with a "plugin" to support iframes:
http://elijahmanor.com/post/jQuery-UI-Dialog-w-Resizable-iFrame.aspx

I use it because it's included in JQueryUI and uses the jquery ui theme you use, which makes for a consistent UI with little cost